# My position gets returned too fast, how to make a promise

Tags: javascript, typescript, geolocation, promise

I have a service:

```
export class CenterMapService {

currentPosition: Position = {
    'latitude': 0,
    'longitude': 0
}

getPosition() {
    console.log('Getting position');

    let that = this;
    navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(
        (position) => {
            that.currentPosition.latitude = position.coords.latitude;
            that.currentPosition.longitude = position.coords.longitude;
        },
        () => {
            alert('Position could not be determined.');
        },
        {
            enableHighAccuracy: true
        }
    );
    }
}
```

Everything is ok, but when I use it:

```
console.log("ON Center map handler");
    this._centerMapService.getPosition();
    this._latitude = this._centerMapService.currentPosition.latitude;
    this._longitude = this._centerMapService.currentPosition.longitude;
    console.log('Current longitude: ', this._latitude);
    console.log('Current longitude: ', this._longitude);
```

For the first call I get:

```
Current longitude: 0
Current latitude: 0
```

just before the getCurrentPosition even executes.
The second call of that function gets me a proper position:

```
Current longitude:  51.5073509
Current longitude:  -0.1277583
```

I believe it is the asynchronous nature of JavaScript, but how would I change it so that the function returns always the second correct result?

Comment: `new Promise((resolve, reject) => navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(resolve, reject, …))` should do it

Answer (score 1):

You are right, this is caused by the asynced nature of the call to `navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition`.

In order to return a promise you need to do something like:

```
export class CenterMapService {
    currentPosition: Position = {
        'latitude': 0,
        'longitude': 0
    }

    getPosition() {
        console.log('Getting position');
        let promise = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
            navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(
                position => {
                    this.currentPosition.latitude = position.coords.latitude;
                    this.currentPosition.longitude = position.coords.longitude;
                    resolve(this.currentPosition);
                },
                () => {
                    reject('Position could not be determined.');
                },
                {
                    enableHighAccuracy: true
                }
            );
        });

        return promise;
    }
}
```

And to use it:

```
this._centerMapService.getPosition().then(position => {
    this._latitude = position.latitude;
    this._longitude = position.longitude;
}, error => alert(error));
```

You'll probably need to change my code a bit for it to work, as I did not test it.

Another thing is that you do not need to use the `that = this` technique as you are using the [arrow function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions) which saves the context.